# Athena AWS parse json to table

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I have my table:

| event_name | value |
| --- | --- |
| event1 | {"link_id":"headphones","spec":"dtx"} |
| event2 | {"geo":"22.12.11"} |

I need to parse every key in separate column, like this:

| event_name | link_id | spec | geo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| event1 | headphones | dtx |  |
| event2 |  |  | 22.12.11 |

I know the solution:

```
WITH my_table (event_name, value) AS (
    values 
    ('event1','{"link_id":"headphones","spec":"dtx"}'),
    ('event2','{"geo":"22.12.11"}')
)
SELECT 
event_name,
json_extract(value, '$.link_id') as link_id,
json_extract(value, '$.spec') as spec,
json_extract(value, '$.geo') as geo
FROM my_table;
```

But can I do this without specify every parameter? I have approx. 100 params.

Comment: can't you parse the json in another language, sql isn't that good in json

Answer (score 1):

> But can I do this without specify every parameter? I have approx. 100 params.

In short - no, you can't if you want them as separate columns. Potentially more idiomatic (and may be suitable for you) SQL approach would be to parse them into separate key-value rows:

```sql
WITH my_table (event_name, value) AS (
    values 
    ('event1','{"link_id":"headphones","spec":"dtx"}'),
    ('event2','{"geo":"22.12.11"}')
)

SELECT event_name,
    key,
    val
FROM my_table,
     unnest(cast(json_parse(value) as map(varchar, json))) as t(key, val);
```

Output:

| event_name | key | val |
| --- | --- | --- |
| event1 | link_id | headphones |
| event1 | spec | dtx |
| event2 | geo | 22.12.11 |

P.S.

Your goal requires either dynamic SQL generation (for example using some "outside" scripting) or dynamic pivoting which is not supported by Presto/Trino ATM.